# Input type for CoreML model using coremltools

Tags: scikit-learn, coremltools

I am trying to convert a `RandomForestClassifier` model of the MNIST dataset into a CoreML model using `coremltools`.

I use `fetch_mldata` from `sklearn.datasets` to import the data; my samples (data) are stored in a Numpy array `X`, and the labels (target) are stored in a Numpy array `Y`.

My model is generated like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X, Y)
```

I then try to convert the model:

```
import coremltools
model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(rfc)
```

The CoreML model input then looks like this:

```
input {
  name: "input"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 784
      dataType: DOUBLE
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the `multiArrayType`. It is much easier to deal with a pixel-buffer in iOS, so various sources point to this syntax (however, they use Caffe rather than sklearn):

```
model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(rfc, image_input_names='data')
```

However, this gives me an error message:

```
TypeError: convert() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image_input_names'
```

I have tried to find the documentation for these parameters, but I have only found some few example using Caffe, and they do not seem to get this error.

Comment: There's no `image_input_names` param in sklearn convert : https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/master/coremltools/converters/sklearn/_converter.py#L10

Comment: Maybe this example can help: https://blog.pusher.com/using-prediction-models-coreml/